# how to append into json file using nodejs

Tags: node.js, json

I have been trying to append into json file but unable to achieve desired results.

My json file:

```
{
"Karan": {
"name": "karan",
"descriptor": [
  343,
  43,
  43
]
},
"Mark": {
"name": "Mark",
"descriptor": [
  343,
  43,
  43
]
}
}
```

Code for appending into file:

```
const fs = require('fs');
const JsonData = require('./JsonFile.json')
let user = {
      Jack:
          {
           name: "Jack",
           descriptor:[28,8,43]
 }};
fs.appendFile("JsonFile.json",","+JSON.stringify(user,null,2),err => {
            if(err) throw err;
            console.log("Done Writing");
 });
 console.log(JsonData);
```

What i am getting as output:

```
{
 "Karan": {
"name": "karan",
"descriptor": [
  343,
  43,
  43
]
},
 "Mark": {
"name": "Mark",
"descriptor": [
  343,
  43,
  43
]
}
 },{
 "Jack": {
"name": "Jack",
"descriptor": [
  28,
  8,
  43
]
}
}
```

What it i was expecting is:

```
{
 "Karan": {
"name": "karan",
"descriptor": [
  343,
  43,
  43
]
},
 "Mark": {
"name": "Mark",
"descriptor": [
  343,
  43,
  43
]
},
 "Jack": {
"name": "Jack",
"descriptor": [
  28,
  8,
  43
]
}
}
```

If we have closer look then the code is appending new contents as whole new entry instead it should append after the ending parentheses of single entry as shown in expected output code.

Could someone help me what should changes be done in code?

Comment: Is there a reason not to just parse the JSON, insert the new item and then write it back whole?

Comment: I think for parsing the JSON we still need to take care of 2extra parentheses which is appended before "Jack" in output

Comment: No I mean parsing the original JSON which is correct into a `users` variable, then go like `users["Jack"] = { name: "Jack", .... }` and then write it back.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to load the data from the file, add the user and then write back to the file, like so:

```
const fs = require("fs");
const jsonData = require("./JsonFile.json");

const user = {
    name: "Jack",
    descriptor: [28,8,43]
};

jsonData[user.name] = user;

fs.writeFileSync("./JsonFile.json", JSON.stringify(jsonData, null, 4));
```

I'd also have a look at the very handy [lowdb](https://github.com/typicode/lowdb) module, this is very good for modifying Json files, with a powerful set of capabilities:

E.g.

```
const low = require('lowdb')
const FileSync = require('lowdb/adapters/FileSync')

const dbFileName = "JsonFile.json";
const adapter = new FileSync(dbFileName)
const db = low(adapter)

const user = {
    name: "Jimmy",
    descriptor: [28,8,43]
};

// Add another entry
db.read().set(user.name, user).write();
```

Comment: Yess, Thanks again I was trying this from 1week & and now your solution looks easy how was i not able to do. Anyways thanks!